# How can I install upwork time tracker in CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

Tags: linux, installation

I didn't find good docs about how I can install upwork on Centos6.6 Is it possible ? I didn't find yum-plugin-copr for centos (I have find only documentation for Fedora)

Comment: [their website does not offer a version for centos](https://www.upwork.com/downloads/new-team-application/os/linux)

Answer (score 1):

I installed upwork on an Ubuntu VM, then loaded it like this:

```
ssh -XCf ubuntu@10.10.10.10 upwork
```

This forwards the graphical interface via SSH from the VM to my screen. It works smoothly so far.